# Start Java jar file during Startup in Linux

Tags: java, linux, startup

**Situation :**

I have jar file on **server PC** (PC act as server), **a.jar**, which will be running infinite loop to listen for TCPIP connection from **client PC**. When connection has been made, **client PC** can send a zip file to **server PC**, **a.jar** will unzip it and execute a script with that zip, which will start another full screen display java file, **b.jar**.

**a.jar** will also trying to run **b.jar** during bootup, if **b.jar** already exist.

---

**Approach 1:**

I wrote a script in **/etc/init.d/** to start **a.jar**, as it's infinite loop, the system hang forever during bootup (*in terminal screen, can't even get into GUI*). I have to boot into single user mode to remove that script in order to boot up normally.

---

**Approach 2:**

When I changed the script to run **a.jar** as a daemon, it runs normally, listen for connection, I can connect to the **server pc** and send zip file.

**Problem:**

1. **b.jar** is  not executed even when execution permission and files are all correctly set.
2. After I sent a zip file, **b.jar** is executed (*because it is connected to a device and that device is activated*). But the full screen display is not shown like it did when executed via terminal.

---

**Reasons of doing so**

It may seems a bit complicated, but because **b.jar** will be constantly updated and it has to be auto start when after update, thus I use **a.jar** to unzip and execute new version fo **b.jar**.

And **b.jar** is required to run as root as it needs to access serial port.

(*Server pc is required to be automated, thus it is required to start **b.jar** during startup and remotely controlled*)

---

**Question**

May I know is there any better way of doing this? Or what did I do wrong? Can someone show me a better script to start it during startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 should work but you must run the java process in the background by adding `&` to the command.

But there are better solutions to run java apps as a deamon.  The above can be considered as a quick fix.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you want to run the application as a daemon, the best solution is using Apache [Jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) :

> Jsvc is a set of libraries and applications for making Java
>   applications run on UNIX more easily.  Jsvc allows the application
>   (e.g. Tomcat) to perform some privileged operations as root (e.g. bind
>   to a port < 1024), and then switch identity to a non-privileged user. 
>   It can run on Win32 via the Cygwin emulation layer, however Win32
>   users may prefer to use procrun instead, which allows the application
>   to run as a Windows Service.